# cardinal commerce payment activity report results

Tags: payment

I have an payment activity report results from cardinal commerce.

[image]

In the In the above report I found Action "None Available".
I am new to cardinal commerce payment. Can any one help me why the action "None Available" is showing for the transaction?
How can I figure out what happening for the transaction with action "None Available"?